# What is the Angular way of dynamically loading a Data-URI scheme image?

Tags: angularjs, data-uri

My server returns a base64-encoded image and I want to send it to the client on some event `foo`. The way I currently have it is as such:

`index.html`

```
...
<img src="{{data}}"></img>
...
```

`controller.js`

```
...
$scope.foo = function (result) {
     $scope.data = result;
}
....
```

When, `foo` happens, `result` is a base64 encoded image and the `img` element starts rendering, as expected. The problem is that when the page loads initially, a request to `/{{data}}` will fire to get the image and 404. **How can I avoid having this rogue request fire when the page initially renders? What is the proper way of doing this, if not how I'm doing it?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prevent the browser attempting to fetch the literal url `/{{data}}`, use the [`ng-src`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSrc) directive instead of `src` in your image tag.